# How to give color to edges of d3js graph?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to give color to the edges but the desire outcome is not according to my desire.The color scheme changes every time I change the JSON file.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="D3js_edges_connected_by_nodes_id.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Weighted Citation Graph</title>
    <style>
        path.link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #666;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        circle {
            fill: #ccc;
            stroke: #333;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        text {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

            text.shadow {
                stroke: #fff;
                stroke-width: 3px;
                stroke-opacity: .8;
            }

        body {
            background-color: white;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .graphContainer {
            text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 white, 1px -1px 0 white, -1px 1px 0 white, 1px 1px 0 white;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function load_graph(text) {

            var color = d3.scale.category20();
            try{
                //var data = JSON.parse(text);
            } catch (e) {
                window.alert("sometext: "+e);
            }

            var data = { "nodes": [{ "id": 127230, "name": "Optimization of query evaluation algorithms", "citation": 26, "group": 7 }, { "id": 127254, "name": "Flow algorithms for parallel query optimization", "citation": 22, "group": 7 }, { "id": 127380, "name": "Randomized approximation algorithms for query optimization problems on two processors", "citation": 14, "group": 7 }, { "id": 127438, "name": "Optimization algorithms for simultaneous multidimensional queries in OLAP environments", "citation": 12, "group": 7 }, { "id": 127063, "name": "Query optimization in database systems", "citation": 230, "group": 7 }, { "id": 127158, "name": "Query optimization in a memory-resident domain relational calculus database system", "citation": 41, "group": 7 }, { "id": 129760, "name": "An Overview of TQuel", "citation": 22, "group": 7 }, { "id": 129867, "name": "ADVISORS", "citation": 10, "group": 7 }, { "id": 129872, "name": "Tellabs and THRIP through the Telkom Centre of Excellence at Rhodes University.", "citation": 10, "group": 7 }, { "id": 127412, "name": "Optimal service ordering in decentralized queries over web services", "citation": 13, "group": 7 }, { "id": 130856, "name": "Queries over Web Services", "citation": 10, "group": 7 }, { "id": 130959, "name": "Exploiting Parallelism to Accelerate Keyword Search On Deep-web Sources", "citation": 10, "group": 7 }, { "id": 131199, "name": "Contents lists available at ScienceDirect Future Generation Computer Systems", "citation": 10, "group": 7 }, { "id": 131211, "name": "Flow Algorithms for Parallel Query Optimization", "citation": 10, "group": 7 }, { "id": 127373, "name": "Multi-query Optimization for On-Line Analytical Processing", "citation": 14, "group": 7 }, { "id": 133379, "name": "Concise descriptions of subsets of structured sets", "citation": 21, "group": 7 }], "links": [{ "source": 127230, "target": 127063, "name": "Most Similar", "value": 100, "grouo": "#1A4876" }, { "source": 127230, "target": 127158, "name": "71 %", "value": 71, "grouo": "#1F75FE" }, { "source": 127230, "target": 129760, "name": "Nothing Matched", "value": 10, "grouo": "#EE204D" }, { "source": 127230, "target": 129867, "name": "Nothing Matched", "value": 10, "grouo": "#EE204D" }, { "source": 127230, "target": 129872, "name": "Nothing Matched", "value": 10, "grouo": "#EE204D" }, { "source": 127230, "target": 127063, "name": "Most Similar", "value": 100, "grouo": "#1A4876" }, { "source": 127230, "target": 127158, "name": "71 %", "value": 71, "grouo": "#1F75FE" }, { "source": 127230, "target": 129760, "name": "Nothing Matched", "value": 10, "grouo": "#EE204D" }, { "source": 127230, "target": 129867, "name": "Nothing Matched", "value": 10, "grouo": "#EE204D" }, { "source": 127230, "target": 129872, "name": "Nothing Matched", "value": 10, "grouo": "#EE204D" }, { "source": 127254, "target": 127412, "name": "5 %", "value": 5, "grouo": "#1F75FE" }, { "source": 127254, "target": 130856, "name": "2 %", "value": 2, "grouo": "#1F75FE" }, { "source": 127254, "target": 130959, "name": "Least Similar", "value": 10, "grouo": "#ACE5EE" }, { "source": 127254, "target": 131199, "name": "Nothing Matched", "value": 10, "grouo": "#EE204D" }, { "source": 127254, "target": 131211, "name": "Most Similar", "value": 100, "grouo": "#1A4876" }, { "source": 127254, "target": 127412, "name": "5 %", "value": 5, "grouo": "#1F75FE" }, { "source": 127254, "target": 130856, "name": "2 %", "value": 2, "grouo": "#1F75FE" }, { "source": 127254, "target": 130959, "name": "Least Similar", "value": 10, "grouo": "#ACE5EE" }, { "source": 127254, "target": 131199, "name": "Nothing Matched", "value": 10, "grouo": "#EE204D" }, { "source": 127254, "target": 131211, "name": "Most Similar", "value": 100, "grouo": "#1A4876" }, { "source": 127438, "target": 127373, "name": "Most Similar", "value": 100, "grouo": "#1A4876" }, { "source": 127438, "target": 133379, "name": "3 %", "value": 3, "grouo": "#1F75FE" }, { "source": 127438, "target": 127373, "name": "Most Similar", "value": 100, "grouo": "#1A4876" }, { "source": 127438, "target": 133379, "name": "3 %", "value": 3, "grouo": "#1F75FE" }] };
            // used to store the number of links between two nodes. 
            // mLinkNum[data.links[i].source + "," + data.links[i].target] = data.links[i].linkindex;
            var mLinkNum = {};

            // sort links first
            // sortLinks();

            data.links.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (a.source > b.source) { return 1; }
                else if (a.source < b.source) { return -1; }
                else {
                    if (a.target > b.target) { return 1; }
                    if (a.target < b.target) { return -1; }
                    else { return 0; }
                }
            })

            // set up linkIndex and linkNumer, because it may possible multiple links share the same source and target node
            setLinkIndexAndNum();

            var w = 1345,
                h = 1000;

            //var w = 3000,
            //    h = 3000;

            var force = d3.layout.force()
            .size([w, h])
            .linkDistance(200)
            .charge(-800)
            .on("tick", tick);

            var svg = d3.select(".graphContainer").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

            var color = d3.scale.category10()
            var edges = [];
            data.links.forEach(function (e) {
                var sourceNode = data.nodes.filter(function (n) {
                    return n.id === e.source;
                })[0],
                    targetNode = data.nodes.filter(function (n) {
                        return n.id === e.target;
                    })[0];

                edges.push({
                    source: sourceNode,
                    target: targetNode,
                    name: e.name,
                    value: e.value,
                    linkindex: e.linkindex,
                    grouo: e.grouo
                });
            });

            console.log(edges)
            force
              .nodes(data.nodes)
              .links(edges)
              .start();

            var path = svg.append("svg:g")
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(edges)
            .enter().append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke-width", function (d, i) {
                console.log(d.value)
                return Math.sqrt(d.value);
            }).style('stroke', function (d) {
                return color(d.grouo);
            });

            //path.append("title").text(function (d) { return d.name });

            var circle = svg.append("svg:g")
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append("svg:circle")
            .attr("r", function (d) {
                return (Math.sqrt(d.citation));
            })
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return color(d.group);
            })
            .call(force.drag);

            circle.append("title").text(function (d) { return d.name });

            //circle.on("click", function () {
            //    d3.select(this)
            //    .attr("r", function (d) {
            //        return (Math.sqrt(d.citation) * 2);
            //    })
            //    .style("fill", "lightsteelblue");
            //});

            circle.on("click", function (d) {
                var thisNode = d.id
                var connected = data.links.filter(function (e) {
                    return e.source === thisNode || e.target === thisNode
                });
                circle.attr("opacity", function (d) {
                    return (connected.map(d => d.source).indexOf(d.id) > -1 || connected.map(d => d.target).indexOf(d.id) > -1) ? 1 : 0.1
                });

                path.attr("opacity", function (d) {
                    return (d.source.id == thisNode || d.target.id == thisNode) ? 1 : 0.1
                });
            })

            circle.on("dblclick", function (d) {
                var thisNode = d.id
                var connected = data.links.filter(function (e) {
                    return e.source === thisNode || e.target === thisNode
                });
                circle.attr("opacity", function (d) {
                    return (connected.map(d => d.source).indexOf(d.id) > -1 || connected.map(d => d.target).indexOf(d.id) > -1) ? 1 : 1
                });

                path.attr("opacity", function (d) {
                    return (d.source.id == thisNode || d.target.id == thisNode) ? 1 : 1
                });
            })

            var text = svg.append("svg:g")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(force.nodes())
            .enter().append("svg:g");
            console.log('test');
            //A copy of the text with a thick white stroke for legibility.
            //text.append("svg:text")
              //.attr("x", 8)
              //.attr("y", ".31em")
              //.attr("class", "shadow")
              //.text(function (d) {
                  //return d.name;
              //});

            text.append("svg:text")
              .attr("x", 8)
              .attr("y", ".31em")
              .text(function (d) {
                 // return d.name;
              });



            // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
            function tick() {
                path.attr("d", function (d, i) {
                    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                       dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                       dr = 75 * d.linkindex;  //linknum is defined above
                    var output = "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
                    //console.log(d)
                    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
                });

                // Add tooltip to the connection path
                path.append("svg:title")
                  .text(function (d, i) {
                      return d.name;
                  });

                circle.attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });

                text.attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });
            }

            // sort the links by source, then target
            function sortLinks1() {
                data.links.sort(function (a, b) {
                    if (a.source > b.source) {
                        return 1;
                    } else if (a.source < b.source) {
                        return -1;
                    } else {
                        if (a.target > b.target) {
                            return 1;
                        }
                        if (a.target < b.target) {
                            return -1;
                        } else {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }



            //any links with duplicate source and target get an incremented 'linknum'
            function setLinkIndexAndNum1() {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.links.length; i++) {
                    if (i != 0 &&
                        data.links[i].source == data.links[i - 1].source &&
                        data.links[i].target == data.links[i - 1].target) {
                        data.links[i].linkindex = data.links[i - 1].linkindex + 1;
                        console.log(data.links[i].linkindex)
                    } else {
                        data.links[i].linkindex = 1;
                        console.log(data.links[i].linkindex)
                    }
                    // save the total number of links between two nodes
                    if (mLinkNum[data.links[i].target + "," + data.links[i].source] !== undefined) {
                        mLinkNum[data.links[i].target + "," + data.links[i].source] = data.links[i].linkindex;
                    } else {
                        mLinkNum[data.links[i].source + "," + data.links[i].target] = data.links[i].linkindex;
                    }
                }
            }


            function setLinkIndexAndNum() {

                for (var i = 0; i < data.links.length; i++) {
                    if (i != 0 &&
                        data.links[i].source == data.links[i - 1].source &&
                        data.links[i].target == data.links[i - 1].target) {
                        data.links[i].linkindex = data.links[i - 1].linkindex + 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        data.links[i].linkindex = 1;
                    };
                };
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <%--<textarea runat="server" id="textarea" cols="80" rows="20"></textarea>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>--%>
    </div>
        <div id="graphContainer" class="graphContainer"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody help me out. thanks! 
If you look at the data variable I have given different colors for each edge according to description of "name" attribute.

Comment: `I am trying to give color to the edges but the desire outcome is not according to my desire`: what is your desire?

Comment: If the name attribute contains "not matched" the color of the link should be red.
If the name attribute contains "least similar" the color of the link should be light blue.
If the name attribute contains "most similar" the color of the link should be dark blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see different colours is because the colour scale d3.scale.category10() - like all d3 ordinal scales (at least in v3) - assigns its colours on a first come first served basis.

https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Ordinal-Scales.md#_ordinal

So if you changed your json so a node with group 'A' is encountered first, then it and subsequent group 'A' nodes will be given the first colour in the scale. If previously it was a node with group 'B' that was encountered first all the nodes with group 'B' would have got that colour instead.

One way to avoid this is to run through your data, collate the groups, order them, and pass them as a domain to your colour scale before setting the colours for individual nodes. That way A, B etc would be in the same order each time.

*However*, this would not help in situations where a change in your data meant particular groups were missing altogether, you'd still see a shift in the colour assignment. For that you'd need to supply a fixed list of all possible groups to assign to the colour scale, even if those groups weren't all in your current data.

PS. You assign `color` to the category20 colour scale, and then later on reassign it to category10. That doesn't have any effect on why you're seeing what you're seeing though as you don't use `color` till afterwards.

PPS. Another thing I've noticed is that your link colours, as defined by the `.grouo` data, are already hexadecimal colour strings. I suspect you don't mean to pass them to the `color` scale and mean to use them as they are i.e. `style ("stroke", function(d) { return d.grouo; ]);`

Comment: Thanks bro... i have got it!